# Are old non-active users going to be removed and miss their privileges?

Tags: support, users

I was wondering if old non-active users would be removed from the site (their user names and profiles) and likewise their privileges and votes. Actually is there any specific rule about that in Islam SE?

I mean if they are not active since long time ago without doing any specific action(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the blog post "[When Is An Account “Abandoned”?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)":

> We **delete cookie-based unregistered accounts** when:
>
> 1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
>
> **AND**
>
> 2. The user has less than 50 reputation, and no visible (not-deleted) posts
>
> We **delete OpenID registered accounts** when:
>
> 1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
>
> **AND**
>
> 2. The user has only 1 reputation, no visible posts, and no other accounts on the network

As far as I know, those are the only cases where an account is *automatically* deleted.  Basically, so long as the account has significantly contributed to the site *at all* (which they pretty much would've had to have done if they had *any* privileges/votes worth worrying about) they're probably safe no matter how long they've been inactive for.

Comment: Uh-huh, I relatively figured out concerning its circumstances (by your brief explicit illustration.) / Well done mate.